# What is an appropriate setting in NDSolve to get feedback about the progress of a long computation?

Tags: numerical-integration, monitoring

Often in computation with an NDSolve-type solver, one hopes to know about its progress.
To this end, I am using `StepMonitor` as follows,

```
NDSolve[eqn, y, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tm}, StepMonitor :> (Print["t=", t]; s++), Method -> method]
```

where the DE is about `y[x,t]`, and `s` is a counter for time step for reference.

This is ok for short calculations, but for long ones with a big terminal time `tm`,
especially with a stiff problem, the output from `StepMonitor` is going to be extremely long due to small time steps. This makes the notebook very long and hard to scroll up and down.
Sometimes, the notebook even breaks down!! Also, I believe the long output consumes a certain amount of memory.

So, I really need an appropriate method to get feedback about the solver's progress. For example, if `tm=1000` is it
possible to get a time step printed out on the notebook every $\Delta t=50$ approximately. Consider the time steps cannot be an exact integer,
so just to print out a time step when it runs up to t>~50, t>~100, t>~150, .... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually use something like this:

```
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock@Infinity, foo};
NDSolve[<ode>, y, {t, 0, 10}, ..., StepMonitor :> (foo = t)]
```

I've also used it to gather other data, like the time of a `WhenEvent` as well as the integration time, along the lines of this:

```
foo = murf = 0.;
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@
  {foo, Style[murf, PrintPrecision -> 17], Clock@Infinity};
sol = NDSolve[{...,
    WhenEvent[..., foo = t; y[t] -> 0]},
  ..., StepMonitor :> (murf = t)]
```

These and similar examples may be found in my answers here:

- [Output of intermediate results from very long NDSolve computation into sequenced CSV files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161560/output-of-intermediate-results-from-very-long-ndsolve-computation-into-sequenced/199228#199228)
- [NDSolve producing non-closed curves for a vector field](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171075/ndsolve-producing-non-closed-curves-for-a-vector-field/171077#171077)
- [How to increase the speed of NDsolve when using WhenEvent](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230449/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-ndsolve-when-using-whenevent/230460#230460)
- [Reducing execution time without compromising on accuracy and precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237429/reducing-execution-time-without-compromising-on-accuracy-and-precision/237444#237444)
- [NDSolve divergence error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268615/ndsolve-divergence-error/268622#268622)

I gave a small explanation of this approach and the usefulness of the running timer `Clock@Infinity` although not in conjunction with `NDSolve` here:

- [Monitoring Apply / @@@ over large lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268051/monitoring-apply-over-large-lists/268103#268103)

Note also the use of `PrintPrecision` in the second example. This allows one to see when the step size gets extremely small.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Dynamic` to show the value of your independent variable increasing as evaluation proceeds in `NDSolve`, perhaps combined with [`ProgressIndicator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProgressIndicator.html) for display:

```
Clear[x, y, i]

ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i], {0, 10}]

NDSolve[
  {y'[x] == y[x], y[0]==1}, y, {x, 0, 10},
  StepMonitor :> (Pause[0.05]; i = x)
]
```

In this example I am purposefully slowing down the evaluation using `Pause[0.05]` in the `StepMonitor`, just for visual effect. Of course you would omit that part in your own code.